# An issue with jQuery parameter parsing

Tags: jquery, parameters

I'm very new to jQuery and I am having an issue with parsing a string value to a function.

I have:

```
    function callAreaData(area) {
        $("area[alt='" + area + "']").hover(function (e) {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").show();
            $("area[alt='" + area + "']").hide();
        }, function () {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").hide();
        });

        $("area[alt='" + area + "']").mousemove(function (e) {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
        });
    }
```

and call it within my

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
          ...
          var a = "Area A";
          callAreaData(a);
          ...
     });
```

It does not work. I know the function itself works because if I replace the parsed values in the function with their string equivalent, as below, it works fine. But that doesn't give me the re-usability I need (as I need to used this function about 10 times over with a different parameter on my web page).

```
     function callAreaData() {
        $("area[alt='Area A']").hover(function () {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").show();
            $("area[alt='Area A']").hide();
        }, function () {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").hide();
        });

        $("area[alt='Area A']").mousemove(function (e) {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
        });
    }
```

It's got to be an easy fix, but I can't see it, so help please?

Thanks in advance, Peter

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Peter please, accept the answer if it was helpful. Thanks (Check the green 'V' mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var area = someArea; // get area from some hidden element 
 $("area[alt='" + area + "']").hover(function (e) {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").show();
            $("area[alt='" + area + "']").hide();
        }, function () {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").hide();
        });

        $("area[alt='" + area + "']").mousemove(function (e) {
            $("div#bodyPlace_popupA").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
        });


});
```